# How can I collapse a multidimensional array into a single array with a common value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Edited to be more clear about my question:**

I have a a multidimensional array that looks like this

```
var data = [
   [2017,   1,       0,       0,       0,       0],
   [2017,   0,       0,       23,      0,       0],
   [2017,   0,       0,       0,       0,       9],
   [2017,   0,       12,      0,       0,       0],
   [2017,   0,       0,       0,       18,      0]
];
```

I'm trying to flatten this data into something that looks like this:

`var data = [2017, 1, 12, 23, 18, 9];`

Where in:

1. The year in Column #0 will be the same throughout rows.
2. For each row, Columns #1 through #5 will only have one non-zero element.

Is there an easy way to do this without having to process the data through multiple for loops? I was hoping maybe there was some native method in the Array type or function in a library out there.

Comment: If I hadn't tried to solve it already I wouldn't have posted it here

Comment: Wow cool, well thanks so much for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array and check take the number if it is higher than the current number:

```js
var data = [
   [2017,   1,       0,       0,       0,       0],
   [2017,   0,       0,       23,      0,       0],
   [2017,   0,       0,       0,       0,       9],
   [2017,   0,       12,      0,       0,       0],
   [2017,   0,       0,       0,       18,      0]
];

let newdata = [];

for (row of data) {
  for (let i = 0; i<row.length; ++i) {
    newdata[i] = (!newdata[i] || row[i] > newdata[i]) ? row[i] : newdata[i];
  }
}
console.log(newdata);
```

outputs:

```
[2017, 1, 12, 23, 18, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in the 1st line to get a column index, and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) all rows to a single non 0 value on that column:

```js
const data = [
   [2017,   1,       0,       0,       0,       0],
   [2017,   0,       0,       23,      0,       0],
   [2017,   0,       0,       0,       0,       9],
   [2017,   0,       12,      0,       0,       0],
   [2017,   0,       0,       0,       18,      0]
];

const result = data[0]
  .map((_, i) => 
    data.reduce((r, e) => r ? r : e[i], 0)
  );
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, based on the next two conditions:

1. The year in Column #0 will be the same throughout rows.
2. For each row, Columns #1 through #5 will only have one non-zero element.

You can use `reduce()` and `findIndex()` on the inners arrays to find the first number greater than zero whose index is not zero, and then put this on the related index of the accumulated result. This will improve perfomance a litle because you don't need to iterate the whole inner array on all the iterations of the reduce method.

```js
var data = [
   [2017, 1, 0,  0,  0,  0],
   [2017, 0, 0,  23, 0,  0],
   [2017, 0, 0,  0,  0,  9],
   [2017, 0, 12, 0,  0,  0],
   [2017, 0, 0,  0,  18, 0]
];

let res = data.slice(1).reduce((acc, curr) =>
{
    let found = curr.findIndex((n, idx) => n > 0 && idx > 0);
    acc[found] = curr[found];
    return acc;

}, data[0]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```